# How can I better organize messy IF statements? (Avoid nesting)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, organization

My code is below (note that this is not about that specific code, it's more of an example I stole from a project).

```js
    if (colliding) { // On ground anims
        if (playerData["xSpeed"] < 1 && playerData["xSpeed"] > -1) {
            if (playerData["animState"] != "idle") {
                if (playerData["lastDirection"] == 1) {
                    spriteSetAnimation(playerData["spriteId"], playerData["animIdleLeft"]);
                } else {
                    spriteSetAnimation(playerData["spriteId"], playerData["animIdleRight"]);
                }
                playerData["animState"] = "idle";
            }
        } else if (playerData["xSpeed"] > 1) {
            if (playerData["animState"] != "runRight") {
                spriteSetAnimation(playerData["spriteId"], playerData["animRunCycleRight"]);
                playerData["animState"] = "runRight";
                playerData["lastDirection"] = 1;
            }
        } else if (playerData["xSpeed"] < -1) {
            if (playerData["animState"] != "runLeft") {
                spriteSetAnimation(playerData["spriteId"], playerData["animRunCycleLeft"]);
                playerData["animState"] = "runLeft";
                playerData["lastDirection"] = -1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (playerData["xSpeed"] < 0.5 && playerData["xSpeed"] > -0.5) {
            if (playerData["animState"] != "jumpStraight") {
                spriteSetAnimation(playerData["spriteId"], playerData["animJumpStraight"]);
                playerData["animState"] = "jumpStraight";
            }
        } else if (playerData["xSpeed"] > 0.5) {
            if (playerData["animState"] != "jumpRight") {
                spriteSetAnimation(playerData["spriteId"], playerData["animJumpRight"]);
                playerData["animState"] = "jumpRight";
            }
        } else if (playerData["xSpeed"] < -0.5) {
            if (playerData["animState"] != "jumpLeft") {
                spriteSetAnimation(playerData["spriteId"], playerData["animJumpLeft"]);
                playerData["animState"] = "jumpLeft";
            }
        }
    }
```

It's not returning anything, so I can not make use of the reverse check. I still have no idea how to fix this kind of spaghetti noodle code.

Comment: `const speed = playerData["xSpeed"];` add that at the top first...

Comment: Remember that if your code works, and you just want help improving it, Stackoverflow is [not the right place to ask](/help/on-topic) and you probably want to ask this over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ there is, that's what the link in my comment points to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was referring to the help center pages on CR. More often than not users post without reading those first, wasting their time as well as the time of potential reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be better organized by breaking it up into functions. For example, a function could be created to handle the animations when the player is on the ground, and a separate function could be created to handle the animations when the player is in the air.

maybe like this:

```js
function runRight(xSpeed,animState,spriteId,animRunCycleRight){
    if(xSpeed > 1){
        if(animState != "runRight"){
            spriteSetAnimation(spriteId,animRunCycleRight);
            animState = "runRight";
        }
    }
}

function runLeft(xSpeed,animState,spriteId,animRunCycleLeft){
    if(xSpeed < -1){
        if(animState != "runLeft"){
            spriteSetAnimation(spriteId,animRunCycleLeft);
            animState = "runLeft";
        }
    }
}
```